# React Native Animation onSubmitEditing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, animation

can someone tell me why this animation will only run after click the second time on "next" button?

I know its something related to my if checks but if setTocuhed triggers correctly (making the things red) why the animate doesn't?

ive already tried a couple of things but none has worked

```
import React from 'react';
import { Animated, Text, View, Easing } from 'react-native';

import { withNavigationFocus } from 'react-navigation';
import Input from '../../components/UI/Input';
import registerStyles from './registerStyles';

type props = {
  navigation: {
    navigate: (arg: string) => void;
  };
};

const validation = (input: string) => {
  if (input.length < 6) {
    return 'min length 6';
  }

  if (input.length > 30) {
    return 'max length: 30';
  }

  return null;
};

const FullName = (props: props) => {
  const [input, setInput] = React.useState<string>('');
  const [touched, setTouched] = React.useState<boolean>(false);
  const [errorMessage, setErrorMessage] = React.useState<string | null>('');

  const viewRef = new Animated.Value(10);

  const animate = () => {
    return Animated.timing(viewRef, {
      toValue: 22,
      easing: Easing.elastic(100),
      duration: 200,
      useNativeDriver: false
    }).start(() => {
      Animated.timing(viewRef, {
        toValue: 10,
        duration: 0,
        useNativeDriver: false
      }).start();
    });
  };

  return (
    <Animated.View style={[registerStyles.screen, { paddingLeft: viewRef }]}>
      <Input
        touched={touched}
        value={input}
        onChange={(value) => setInput(value)}
        autoFocus={true}
        returnKeyType='next'
        label='Full name'
        onSubmitEditing={() => {
          const validate = validation(input);
          setErrorMessage(() => validate);

          if (validate === null) {
            setInput(() => '');
            setTouched(() => false);
            props.navigation.navigate('Email');
            return;
          }
          if (validate !== null) {
            animate();
            setTouched(() => true);
          }
        }}
      />
      <Text style={registerStyles.error}>{touched && errorMessage}</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

export default withNavigationFocus(FullName);
```

this is the Input component if needed:

```
const Input = (props: IInput) => {
  const errorColor = props.touched ? colors.red : colors.black;
  const errorStyles = {
    textField: {
      borderBottomColor: errorColor
    },
    label: {
      color: errorColor
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.inputContainer}>
      <Text style={[styles.label, errorStyles.label]}>{props.label}</Text>
      <TextInput
        autoCapitalize={props.autoCapitalize}
        onChangeText={(value) => props.onChange(value)}
        value={props.value}
        autoFocus={props.autoFocus}
        ref={(input) => {
          if (props.inputRef) {
            return props.inputRef(input);
          }
        }}
        style={[styles.textField, errorStyles.textField]}
        onSubmitEditing={props.onSubmitEditing}
        returnKeyType={props.returnKeyType}
        blurOnSubmit={false}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Wha do you want to achieve?

Comment: basically, if user write something wrong, the input should display red and play this animation. If user write something right, go to next page, clean everything and stuff. Everything works fine, but the animation doesn't play on the current render, only on next render cycle. In other words, first time user press "next" on keyboard, he won't see. Only from the second and on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `viewRef` inside `useRef` hook.

`const viewRef = React.useRef(new Animated.Value(10)).current;`

In this case, React will keep tracking its value and don't lose it after rerendering.